# Store integers as integers and not as floats

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, type-conversion

I do the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df_texts = pd.read_csv('data_texts.csv', keep_default_na=True)

for index, row in df_texts.iterrows():   

    list_of_words = row['text'].split()

    df_texts.loc[index, '#_words'] = len(list_of_words)

    list_of_unique_words = set(list_of_words)  

    df_texts.loc[index, '#_unique_words'] = len(list_of_unique_words)
```

The problem is that the numbers at the `#_words` and at the `#_unique_words` columns are stored as floats even though they are integers.

Just to clarify that these two columns do not pre-exist in the .csv which I read (`pd.read_csv`) but I create them in the `for` loop.

How can I directly store them as integers?

Comment: @iamklaus cool but still my question is: How can I directly store them as integers?

Comment: change the columns datatype after you r done inserting values in the column or create a list of values and later insert.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do this and directly get ints is to assign the new columns directly, and avoid iterating through the dataframe altogether.

With some dummy data for an example:

```
import pandas as pd
texts = ['word1 word2 word3', 'word1 word2 word1', 'word3']

df_texts = pd.DataFrame(texts, columns = ['text'])
                text
0  word1 word2 word3
1  word1 word2 word1
2              word3
```

Calculate the length for all rows using the text column separately and then assign.

```
temp = df_texts['text'].str.split()
df_texts['#_words'] = [len(row) for row in temp] #iterates and creates a list of all lengths. assign to df
df_texts['#_unique_words'] = [len(set(row)) for row in temp]

print(df_texts)
#Output:
                text  #_words  #_unique_words
0  word1 word2 word3        3               3
1  word1 word2 word1        3               2
2              word3        1               1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply int function to needed column:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({
    'n':[1.12, 1.2345, 5.234]
})
df['n'] = df['n'].apply(lambda x: int(x))
df
```

```
    n
0   1
1   1
2   5
```

Comment: I could use `pd.to_numeric()` too I think (which may be more efficient than your solution above) but still I am looking for (if it exists) something which is even more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you create the column by assigning a value to a single row, all the other rows are implicitly initialized to `NaN`, which is a floating point value. This forces the entire column to `float`.

(You will also notice this if you try to convert the column using `df_texts['#_words'] = df_texts['#_words'].astype(int)` before all values have been set. It will fail because `NaN` cannot be converted to `int`.)

Therefore, the column can't become an integer column until all values are set. The problem goes away if you initialize the entire column with `df_texts['#_words'] = 0` before the loop.

**Edit:** Also, as the other answers have pointed out, this assignment can be done without using a loop in the first place.